# Classifying data in python

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

[image: Dataset]

I have a data set something like the one above read into python using the read_csv function. What I would like to do is

1. Change the rings column into a class column where 1-5 rings is class 1, 5-10 rings is class 2 and so on. Right now I have a for loop that looks like this

   ```
   while j<4177 :
       if (X[j][7]) < 9:
           (X[j][7]) = 1
       elif (X[j][7]) is 9 | (X[j][8]) is 10:
           (X[j][7]) = 2
       else:
           (X[j][7]) = 3
       j=j+1
   ```

   What is a more efficient way to do this?
2. Assuming I would like to keep my ring column and instead add another column with the classes, what's the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html):

```
np.random.seed(100)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(20, size=(20,2)), columns=['a','ring'])
print (df)
     a  ring
0    8     3
1    7    15
2   16    10
3    2     2
4    2    14
5    2    17
6   16    15
7    4    11
8   16     9
9    2    12
10   4     1
11  13    19
12   4     4
13   3     7
14  17    15
15   1    14
16   7    16
17   2     9
18  19     2
19  14    17
```

```
classes = 4

bins = np.linspace(0, classes * 5, classes + 1)
labels=['class ' + str(i + 1) for i in range(classes)]
print (bins)
[  0.   5.  10.  15.  20.]
print (labels)
['class 1', 'class 2', 'class 3', 'class 4']

df['label'] = pd.cut(df['ring'], bins=bins, labels=labels)
print (df)
     a  ring    label
0    8     3  class 1
1    7    15  class 3
2   16    10  class 2
3    2     2  class 1
4    2    14  class 3
5    2    17  class 4
6   16    15  class 3
7    4    11  class 3
8   16     9  class 2
9    2    12  class 3
10   4     1  class 1
11  13    19  class 4
12   4     4  class 1
13   3     7  class 2
14  17    15  class 3
15   1    14  class 3
16   7    16  class 4
17   2     9  class 2
18  19     2  class 1
19  14    17  class 4
```